# LGSideMenuBar background color change

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicolor

I am using LGSideMenuController in my project, i have changed the color of cells in my table view but unable to change the remaining view color. If anyone is familiar with LGSideMenuController plz help.

See image for ref.[image: the cell color i changed is graycolor. I want to make the remaining green background to gray]

Comment: which color do you want to change?  green or gray?

Comment: in which color u want to change

Comment: That gray color is background of tablview's cell that you are used in ViewController. just set the clear color of your tableview cell.

Comment: i want it gray @Mr.Bond

Comment: I want to make it gray @NitinGohel

Comment: find the image of background setting in code and set the bg color gray instead of image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove image and Add UIcolor of background:

add below line in MainViewController in LGsidemenu file:

```
    self.leftViewBackgroundColor =[UIColor grayColor];
```

Comment: perfect @Mr. Bond :) Thanx a lot

Comment: I need one more help @Mr. Bond .. My first cell is a tableViewController , whenever i click on it , the table appers with a jump. Some part is under navigation and the it resizes it self.

Comment: Wait, i will check in demo.@iDeveloper

Comment: can you show me your Project video of tableviewcontroller. because i will easily expalin that what you need. @iDeveloper

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108628/discussion-between-ideveloper-and-mr-bond).

Comment: Hello @Mr.Bond, I tried changing the color in the LGSideMenuController.m pod file but the color doesn't change. Its white as natural. Any other way?